# Two-dimensional iir filter

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I am trying to use a very simple 2d IIR lowpass filter (a may vary from zero to one), analogous to

```
y' = -a*y + x
```

As if solved with the forward euler method.

```
        for(uint32_t row = 1; row < img.height(); ++row)
        {
            for(uint32_t col = 1; col < img.width(); ++col)
            {
                auto output_x = img_in(col, row) + img(col - 1, row) * (1.0f - a);
                auto output_y = img_in(col, row) + img(col, row - 1) * (1.0f - a);

                auto sum = 0.5f*(output_x + output_y);

                img(col, row) = sum;
            }
        }
```

img_in is the source image, and img is the image that is being written to.

Normailzed output for a = 0, with white noise as input looks like this:

[image: brownian noise attempt]

As can be seen the sum of the x-filter and y-filter is a diagonal result. Is there at trick to solve this issue? I guess that the problem comes from the fact that the approximation of the derivatives are not central differences, but backward differences.

I have tried to fill `img(col - 1, row)` also to compensate, but then, the lines become vertical instead.

Comment: You lack so much info here. first an IIR filter can do tons of things, what where you attempting to do? Why does your code read from `img` and `img_in` instead from the same image? Why the diagonal is wrong? It is not if you wanted a diagonal filer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Well, normally you would like to have isotropic behaviour

Comment: you completely miss the point. An Infinite Impulse Response filter is a type of filter, which contains infinite possible sub-types. IIR refers to the way the filter is defined and some few properties, but a mean filter, a Chevichev filter, a Bessel filter, an edge detector filter, are all IIR. What you have there is a IIR, so technically its working. You just have not defined what you want to do with the IIR, what effect you want the filter to have.

Comment: Ah, I see that since you edited to add "lowpass filter". Good. Now instead of making up your own filter, have you looked at the widely studied fields of image filters, and chosen one?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Except that I have a filter prototype, with a suitable parameterization, I want to extend. Notice that a = 0 would result in brownian noise for a certain input, while a = 1 basically turns the filter off. One implementation would be to work in frequency domain and transform data using FFT, but that would more computations, and also would not give the same result: Any FFT based filter is a FIR filter, which would never have the same impulse response.